# Graph Theory Function (Thomassen)

Tags: graph-theory

> Thomassen ($1983$): Prove that there exists a function $f : N → N$ such
> that every graph of minimum degree at least $3$ and girth at least
> *f(r)* has a K$_{r}$ minor, for every $r ∈ N$.

So my book says that the proof results from theses two Lemmas (**BOLDED**), but I am having a hard time seeing the connections.

I just need to know/understand how it results from the two lemmas (I want to say this problem might just be some simple algebraic manipulation of the equations to find the functions, but I am having a hard time figuring it out. Maybe solve for a $k$ in terms of $r$ then plug it in somewhere?)

This is from the book:

> "There exists a function $f: N → N$ such that every graph of minimum
> degree at least $3$ and girth at least $f(r)$ has a $K_r$ minor, for all
> *r∈ N*.
>
> Proof.
>
> We prove the theorem with $f(r) := 8 log r + 4 log(log r)+ c $, for some constant $c∈R$. Let $k = k(r)∈N$ be minimal with $3·2k$
> $≥ c′r\sqrt{logr}$, where $c′∈R$ is the constant from Theorem $7.2.3.$
> Then for a suitable constant $c∈R$ we have $8k + 3 ≥ 8 log r +$
> $4log(log > r)+ c$,
> and the **result follows by Lemma $1$ and $2$** (below)."
>
> $1.$ *(Kostochka $1982$)* There exists a constant $c∈R$ such that for every $r ∈ N$, every graph $G$ of average degree $d(G) ≥ c ·r\sqrt{logr}$ contains a K$_r$ as a minor. Up to the value of $c$, this bound is best
> possible as a function of $r$.
>
> $2.$ Let $d, k ∈ N$ with $d≥3$ and let $G$ be a graph of minimum degree $\delta(G)≥d$ and girth $g(G)≥ 8k+3$. Then $G$ has a minor $H$ of minimum
> $\delta(H) ≥ \{d(d − 1)\}^k$.

Comment: It might help to point people to the results you're referring to.  I think perhaps the Lemma you mention is Thomassen's first result in this paper:  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895683900679#.  The result by Kostochka is that any graph of average degree $c' r \sqrt{\log r}$ contains a $K_r$ minor.

Comment: @TylerSeacrest I edited it, hopefully that makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @Lindsey I have a recollection of seeing this thing proven in Diestel's book.

Comment: @Jernej Yes, this is from Diestal's book, he says that Thomassen's follows from the two lemmas, but I'm having a hard time seeing it

Comment: Btw doesn't the claim follows quickly from 1 and 2? By lemma $2$ you get a minor with large average degree provided that your graph has large girth. By picking a suitably large girth , the min degree is then large enough so that the average degree satisfies the conditions of lemma 1 giving you the desired complete graph as a minor. Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: I think I am just looking for a specific function that I can see from the two Lemma's that prove it and maybe that's not what I should be thinking